# Parameter passing in react native navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react-native and react-navigation. How do I pass params between navigators? i.e. Passing some parameters from

> NavigatorA to the another screen of NavigatorB

See below for my Navigator setup.

```
    const MobileNumberEntryStack = StackNavigator({
    MobileNumberEntry: MobileNumberEntryScreen
});

const AuthStack = StackNavigator({
    SignIn: SignInScreen,
    SignUp: SignUpScreen
});

const AppNavigator = SwitchNavigator({
    Loading: LoadingScreen,
    App: TabNavigator,
    Auth: AuthStack,
    MobileNumberEntryStack: MobileNumberEntryStack,
});

export default AppNavigator;
```

In my `LoadingScreen` I am fetching some data and from there I am switching to `MobileNumberEntryStack` by calling

```
`this.props.navigation.navigate('MobileNumberEntryStack', { user` })
```

But I am not getting user in `MobileNumberEntryScreen`. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Could you show the MobileNumberEntryScreen?

Comment: Please Share MobileNumberEntryScreen.

Comment: Learn about redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code into **AppNavigator** and then try to navigate into it.

```
 MobileNumberEntryStack: {
        screen: MobileNumberEntryStack,
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access that variable you sent with `this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName', {user})` like this `this.props.navigation.state.params.user` this should work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code for send params from NavigatorA :

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
   itemId: 86,
   otherParam: 'anything you want here',
});
```

and use this code to receive params in NavigatorB:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value');
```

Comment: when I log the,         console.log("@Param", this.props.navigation.state.params); In the NavB,
 I get Undefined

Comment: try console.log("@Param", otherParam ); in NavB

Comment: @param: undefined:/, **without using the default value**